# Models and Controllers usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find out the correct relation and usage between models and controllers as even though I've read enough I'm still missing something because each time I form a connection with an action I keep getting errors. For example;

Controller.rb

```
def destroy
    Map.clear
end
```

#### Model.rb

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base

     def self.clear
         update_attritube something or order.
     end

end
```

So having self.clear in the model I was thinking that Map.clear would do it in the Controller. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: I think you should look up/read on topics on Models and Class and Instance methods/variables, as your clear method demonstrates a very high lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your controller method - it's your class method `clear` that is flawed.  This code:

```
def self.clear
  update_attribute(...)
end
```

will fail because `update_attribute` (or `update_attributes`) is not a valid ActiveRecord class method - it's meant to be called on a model instance.  You can use the `update_all(...)` method instead, although that depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish within this method.

If you actually mean to update/soft-delete a single record, then you should not be working at the class level, but rather fetching a single record (based on the passed id - which you are passing, right?) and calling some method on *that* instance to update it.

Comment: PinnyM can I do this; in controller `def destroy something = Something.find(params[:id]) something.cancel end` and in model have 'class Something < ActiveRecord::Base def cancel update_attritube(table_field => 'true') end end` something like that. I feel like I have a brain fart. I keep reading and looking at examples but can't figure it out. I thought if you define something in Model to do something with database, like update_attritube(s) then you could call that in the controller.

Comment: @user2419316: Your controller should be making simple calls on the model(s).  Calling `something.update_attribute(some_field: true)` is fine, but calling `something.cancel` where `.cancel` calls `update_attribute` seems even cleaner (if that's what you want as the result).  There is nothing wrong with your approach that I can see.  Is the result now what you are expecting?

Comment: Not sure why but if I place `something.something` or `@something.something` in the controller and def something update_attribute end in model, I get error that update_attritube(s) is `not defined for class(0x039393)`. Maybe I have to do def something `@something = Something.find(:all) @something.update_attritube(:some => some) end`. Just trying to understand all of this and I learn based on examples faster then reading an explanation if you know what I mean.

Comment: This can't be solved in the abstract without a very lengthy conversation, for which this is not the right forum.  Please post the entire code you are actually using (including the view used to call the controller action, the controller action itself, and any relevant model code).